# Mobile browser column view issues material design (css)

Tags: css, angularjs, flexbox, material-design

I have an Angular MD template that uses a row layout on large screens and a column layout on mobile devices. However, in most standard browsers on mobile phones I get a weird result where the columns are too big. I have different screenschots of how it should look.

[PC view](http://oi60.tinypic.com/2u9isrc.jpg)

[Mobile view how it looks on Chrome/ff/Opera](http://oi60.tinypic.com/2607mup.jpg)

[Mobile standard browser view (problem)](http://oi58.tinypic.com/15d30w0.jpg)

My simplified code (of the 3 rows/columns) is as follows

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
  <div flex="50" flex-sm="90" flex-md="80" class="row3" layout="row" layout-sm="column">
    <div flex="40" flex-sm="100" layout="row" layout-align "center start">
      <!-- first column -->
    </div>

    <div flex="20" flex-sm="100" style="background: #2AFF00">
      <!-- second column -->
    </div>

    <div flex="40" flex-sm="100" layout="row" layout-align="center start">
      <!-- Third column -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: flexbox is not [supported everywhere yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: Please clarify what behaviour you want and in which browsers it doesn't work. If you could provide a codepen or js fiddle too it would be splendid.
Flexbox should work fine in all browsers used today.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a [demo on codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbQEZz?editors=110) with Chrome, but it seems Safari 5.1.7 (windows), as BotanMan said, that flexbox isn't supported and I couldn't even test it on codepen with IE11.

```
<div layout-sm="column" layout="row" layout-align="center center" layout-padding>
  <div class="row3" layout="row" layout-sm="column">
    <div flex-sm="100" flex="40" layout="column" layout-align="start center" layout-margin>
      <div class="img"></div>
      <h2>Enter the product's serial number</h2>
      <button class="md-button">Verify the product</button>
    </div>

    <div flex-sm="100" flex="20" layout-margin layout-padding style="background: #2AFF00">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum temporibus iure voluptas recusandae molestiae saepe doloremque velit, consequatur minus sint expedita laboriosam magni architecto omnis, reprehenderit labore maxime ea, fugiat officiis. Commodi, aliquam nisi consequatur!</p>
      <p>Enim aliquam nihil nam alias consequuntur amet fuga suscipit dolores deleniti ut, quo numquam quaerat harum cupiditate dolore veritatis a sit, nesciunt aut magni commodi sed doloremque quis. Voluptatum cupiditate commodi, magni consequatur, eveniet aut.</p>
      <p>Sit quae natus quibusdam nesciunt quo rem totam sequi dolorem sint eum perspiciatis molestias illum debitis, nobis eos dolorum. Sunt, perspiciatis voluptas possimus, laboriosam officiis recusandae animi in, nisi suscipit ipsum eaque assumenda odit laudantium!</p>
    </div>

    <div flex-sm="100" flex="40" layout="column" layout-align="start center" layout-margin>
      <div class="img"></div>
      <h2>Click the button below to enable your webcam and start the scanning</h2>
      <button class="md-button">Scan W/ webcam</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox), every latest versions of browsers should be able to use flexbox. *See the link for further compatibility infos.

*BTW you are missing one '=' in the second 'layout-align' directive.